# how to insert column name in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe

```
             0
0     0.164560
1     0.000000
2     0.350000
3     0.700000
    ...
3778  0.350000
3779  0.000000
3780  0.137500
3781  0.253333
```

I want to add an doc-id column starting with index 1 and change the value of column 0 to value.
Expected output is

```
doc-id       value
    1     0.164560
    2     0.000000
    3     0.350000
    4     0.700000
        ...
```

How can I do that?

Comment: `df.reindex(df.index+1)`

Answer (score 2):

Use [`insert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html) and then `rename`:

```
df.insert(0, 'doc-id', df.index + 1)
df = df.rename(columns={0:'value'})

print (df)
      doc-id     value
0          1  0.164560
1          2  0.000000
2          3  0.350000
3          4  0.700000
3778    3778  0.350000
3779    3779  0.000000
3780    3780  0.137500
3781    3781  0.253333
```

If need change index add `1` and then use `rename` with [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
df.index +=1
df = df.rename(columns={0:'value'}).rename_axis('doc-id')
print (df)
           value
doc-id          
1       0.164560
2       0.000000
3       0.350000
4       0.700000
3779    0.350000
3780    0.000000
3781    0.137500
3782    0.253333
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to treat this new column as an Index for the dataframe (as opposed to a column of data):

```
# adjust the index to start at 1 instead of 0
df.reindex(df.index+1, copy=False)
# add the doc_id name
df.index.name = "doc_id"
```